# automatically fill a textbox at moment a value appeared in another textbox

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have 4 text boxes.

I have written the function for to get the sum of 1st and 2nd textboxes in the 3rd textbox. Everything is fine till now.

I am getting the sum of 1st and 2nd textbox in the 3rd textbox.

What I want is that I want is to have the value automatically in the 4th text box at the moment the sum of 1st and 2nd txtbox appear in the 3rd textbox.

---

txt1   | txt2 | (sum) |

---

total____           | txt4  |

---

I tried to call a function in the onchange on 3rd txt box, but its not working. But if I type any number in the 3rd textbox it will appear in the 4th textbox.

i want to fill the txt4 with the sum that i already got in txt 3

Comment: Please post the HTML and script - for example in the snippet editor to show what you have tried

Comment: want to fill the txt4 with the sum that i already got in txt 3

Comment: Please SHOW SOME HTML and CODE! This question will likely be closed as off topic if you do not

Answer (score 0):

So as far as i understand, you already have a function to get the values from textbox 1 and textbox 2 into textbox 3, so you can just write one line more in this function which takes the content from textbox 3 and fills it into textbox 4? or am i missing something?

```
//your code to fill textbox 3
document.getElementById('textbox4').value = document.getElementById('textbox3').value;
```

Comment: want to fill the txt4 with the sum that i already got in txt 3

Comment: What do you mean by "sum"? Can't you just take the value from txt3 and fill txt4 with it?

Comment: "What I want is that I want to have the sum value automatically in the 4th text box at the moment the sum of 1st and 2nd txtbox appear in the 3rd textbox."